# Is it possible to defer the return value check when using the NotNullWhen attribute?

Tags: c#

In a C# nullable reference types context, the `NotNullWhen` attribute can be used to tell the compiler that if a method's return value is a certain value, a certain out parameter won't be null.  The example given on MS Docs has the return value being used immediately in an `if` statement:

```
private bool outputIfInputValid(string input, [NotNullWhen(returnValue: true)] out string? output) {
    output = null;
    if (input == "valid") {
        output = "set";
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public void testMethod() {
    if (outputIfInputValid("valid", out string? output)) {
        string nonNullString = output;
        // ^ No error/warning, because output can't be null
    }
}
```

However, what if I need to defer the checking because I need to execute some other code first, perhaps only using `output` inside some other closure?

```
private bool outputIfInputValid(string input, [NotNullWhen(returnValue: true)] out string? output) {
    output = null;
    if (input == "valid") {
        output = "set";
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public void testMethod() {
    bool wasSet = outputIfInputValid("valid", out string? output);

    // [some code...]

    using (getLock()) {
        if (wasSet) {
            string nonNullString = output;
            // ^ Gives error/warning because 'output is a possible null value'
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately in this case it seems the compiler can't figure out that the `wasSet` boolean being true guarantees that `output` will be set to non-null.  Is there any way I can work around this?

Comment: Why not just return `output` instead? Then you can just check `== null` normally. If you want a `bool` for some other reason, you can return `(bool, string?)`. There is no reason to use `NotNullWhen` if you are not using this immediately in an `if`.

Comment: I guess I could do that although the code looks nicer / more readable if I say `if wasSet` because in my case `wasSet` is actually more like `doThisAction`, so I'm saying `if doThisAction` rather than `if (varA isn't null and varB isn't null)`.

Comment: You can see the warning [in fiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ka3yMg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of `NotNullWhen` on `out` parameters is to allow null-tracking to work correctly even when the method is used in an `if`. That is, you can avoid this kind of code:

```
bool success = Foo.TryParse(something, out var foo);
if (success && foo != null) {
    // Compiler knows that foo is non-null here
}
```

and write this instead:

```
if (Foo.TryParse(something, out var foo)) {
    // Compiler knows that foo is non-null here
}
```

If you are not calling the method in an `if`, you don't need `NotNullWhen`. You can just return the string and let the caller check whether it is null whenever necessary.

```
private string? outputIfInputValid(string input) {
    if (input == "valid") {
        return "set";
    }
    return null;
}
```

```
string? output = outputIfInputValid("valid");
// [some code...]

using (...) {
    if (output != null) {
        string nonNullString = s; // OK!
    }
}
```

If you find this `output != null` check rather unreadable, and would like to use a custom name like `canDoXXX`, you can simply wrap this in a local function:

```
bool CanDoXXX([NotNullWhen(true)] string? s) => s != null;
string? output = outputIfInputValid("valid");
// [some code...]

using (...) {
    if (CanDoXXX(output)) {
        string nonNullString = output;
    }
}
```

Alternatively the local function can capture `output`:

```
// this can be reused
bool CheckNull<T>(T? target, [NotNullWhen(true)] out T? x) {
    x = target;
    return x != null;
}

string? output = outputIfInputValid("valid");

bool CanDoXXX([NotNullWhen(true)] out string? s) => 
    CheckNull(output, out s);

using (...) {
    if (CanDoXXX(out var nonNullString)) {
        // nonNullString is not null here, you can directly use it
    }
}
```

Comment: After seeing this solution I would prefer disabling the warning by using [null-forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving).